# pyqt5 перенос данных в новое окно

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Помогите реализовать перенос текста из полей в новое окно, как простые надписи.

Вот исходные поля и кнопки, но вот реализацию переноса данных я так и не могу понять.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(409, 223)
        MainWindow.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.DefaultContextMenu)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 251, 31))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.textEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 60, 251, 31))
        self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")
        self.textEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 100, 251, 31))
        self.textEdit_3.setObjectName("textEdit_3")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 20, 61, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 70, 71, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 110, 121, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 140, 131, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 140, 121, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 409, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Имя"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Фамилия"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Дата рождения"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Загрузить фото"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Сгенерировать"))

class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton2.clicked.connect(self.clicked_button_2)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Вот второе окно

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(416, 219)
        MainWindow.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.DefaultContextMenu)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 10, 61, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 60, 71, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 100, 121, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 20, 121, 16))
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 60, 121, 16))
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 100, 121, 16))
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 416, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Имя"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Фамилия"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Дата рождения"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "//////////////"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "//////////////"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "//////////////"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

Немного упорядочил ваши виджеты и вставил в макет:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow2(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(416, 219)
        MainWindow.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.DefaultContextMenu)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 10, 61, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 60, 71, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 100, 121, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 20, 121, 16))
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 60, 121, 16))
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 100, 121, 16))
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 416, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Window2"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Имя"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Фамилия"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Дата рождения"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "//////////////"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "//////////////"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "//////////////"))


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(409, 223)
        MainWindow.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.DefaultContextMenu)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
#        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)            # ---
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)        
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 251, 31))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 60, 251, 31))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")

#        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)          # ---
#        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 100, 251, 31))
#        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")

        self.dateEdit = QtWidgets.QDateEdit()                               # +++

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 20, 61, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 70, 71, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 110, 121, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 140, 131, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 140, 121, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 409, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Имя"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Фамилия"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Дата рождения"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Загрузить фото"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Передать данные в новое окно"))


class Window2(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow2):
    def __init__(self):  
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.labelImage = QtWidgets.QLabel() 
        self.labelImage.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.label,   0, 1)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.label_4, 0, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.label_2, 1, 1)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.label_5, 1, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.label_3, 2, 1)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.label_6, 2, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.labelImage, 3, 0, 1, 2)


class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.seleccionarImagen)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.clicked_button_2)
        self.dateEdit.dateChanged.connect(self.on_date_change)

        self.lblDate = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.labelImage = QtWidgets.QLabel()                

        self.grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.lineEdit,   0, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.label,      0, 1)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2, 1, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.label_2,    1, 1)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.dateEdit,   2, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.label_3,    2, 1)

        self.grid.addWidget(self.labelImage, 3, 0)

        self.grid.addWidget(self.pushButton, 4, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 4, 1)   

        self.window2 = Window2()      

    def clicked_button_2(self):
        self.window2.label_4.setText(self.lineEdit.text())
        self.window2.label_5.setText(self.lineEdit_2.text())
        self.window2.label_6.setText(self.lblDate.text())
        self.window2.show()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QDate)
    def on_date_change(self, dateEdit: QtCore.QDate) -> None:
        self.lblDate.setText(dateEdit.toString("yyyy-MM-dd"))

    def seleccionarImagen(self):
        imagen, extension = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(      
            self, 
            "Выбор фото", 
            "",
            "Image (*.png *.jpg)",
            options=QtWidgets.QFileDialog.Options())

        if imagen:
            pixmapImagen = QtGui.QPixmap(imagen).scaled(112, 128,
                               QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio,
                               QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)
            self.labelImage.setPixmap(pixmapImagen)  

            self.window2.labelImage.setPixmap(pixmapImagen)

            self.grid.addWidget(self.labelImage, 3, 0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = Main()                                  # --- QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
#    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
#    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]